# Google analytics incorrect event reporting

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

I am using the following code in a WordPress sidebar widget, to load random advertisement which is working perfectly. This code also sends impressions to google Analytics. Now the issue is that this code sends impressions to all advertisements. not only the advertisement loaded randomly.
I have pasted the code in the below url.

http://pastebin.com/TrxDhLXa

```
<script>
var value1 = 'top_1st';
var value2 = 'top_2nd';
var value3 = 'top_3rd';
var chosenValue = Math.random() < 0.5 ? value1 : value2 : value3;
var chosenDiv = document.getElementById(chosenValue);
chosenDiv.style.display = "block";
</script>

<div id="inline" class="various2">
      <div style="display: none;" id="top_1st">
         <a href="http://scicom.mv" onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'TopBannerSciCom', 'click','SciComTopTuition',1.00, {'nonInteraction': 1});" ><img width="100%" style="border: 0px" src="http://ads.esfiya.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/tuition_top.jpg" alt="" /></a>
<img width=0 height=0 src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==" onload="ga('send', 'event', 'TopBannerSciCom', 'impression','SciComTopTuition',2.00, {'nonInteraction': 1});"/>
       </div>
    <div style="display: none;" id="top_2nd">
           <a href="http://scicom.mv" onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'TopBannerSciCom', 'click','SciComTopEng',1.00, {'nonInteraction': 1});" ><img width="100%" style="border: 0px" src="http://ads.esfiya.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/eng_top.jpg" alt="" /></a>
<img width=0 height=0 src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==" onload="ga('send', 'event', 'TopBannerSciCom', 'impression','SciComTopEng',2.00, {'nonInteraction': 1});"/>
       </div>

<div style="display: none;" id="top_3rd">
           <a href="http://scicom.mv" onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'TopBannerAdHere', 'click','TopAdHere',1.00, {'nonInteraction': 1});" ><img width="100%" style="border: 0px" src="http://ads.esfiya.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/ad-here-red700x140.jpg" alt="" /></a>
<img width=0 height=0 src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==" onload="ga('send', 'event', 'TopBannerAdHere', 'impression','TopAdHere',2.00, {'nonInteraction': 1});"/>
       </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This probably isn't the problem, but your shorthand-if has three values: var chosenValue = Math.random() < 0.5 ? value1 : value2 : value3. Also, you are firing an event on each image load, so isn't it expected that you would have impressions on all ads? Sorry, just need some clarification.

Comment: Please add your code here not on pastebin in the future.

Answer (score 0):

### Impressions

All your advertisements are loaded, so all three onload scripts will take effect. They are only not visible because display: none.

You have to attack this impression event only to desired advertisement.

### Ternary operator

```
Math.random() < 0.5 ? value1 : value2 : value3;
```

Try this instead:

```
var options = ['top_1st','top_2nd','top_3rd']; 
var chosenValue = options[Math.floor(Math.random()*options.length)];
```

### Non-interaction flag on onclick

Why do you use non-interaction flag on onclick event? it is users interaction, so it would be interactive event.

```
onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'TopBannerSciCom', 'click','SciComTopEng',1.00);"
```